# How to speed up oracle sql query on column that has little cardinality

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has around 20 million rows, and I will do query that is filtered against two columns,say, `col1`, `col2`.

For example,

```
select * from tmp where col1 = '1aagacdaafasd' and col2 in ('X','Y','Z')
```

1. For `col1`, I have created an index for column `col1`, and it improves performance dramatically.
2. For `col2`, the problem here is that `col2` has only a few different values(small cardinality).I would ask whether it will improve performance if  I also create index on `col2`.

That is, I have created two index, one for `col1`, the other for `col2`.

Comment: actually is better if you create a composite index for `(col1, col2)`

Comment: You question is too broad to answer because we cannot possibly know all there is to know about your entire application. The question you should be asking is this: how can I compare the performance of one execution of a query with the performance of another query? The answer to that question would probably mean creating and using hidden indexes while you trace the execution and profile the results to see which one is best for you. But it's not just best for one query, it involves you trying to evaluate *all* SQL statements that execute upon this table.

Comment: agree with you.

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a second index on col2 will likely provide no benefit.

The best index for this query is either:

- an index on just col1
- a single index on both col1, col2

Exactly which is best will depend on your data distribution.  You should test these against each other.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
select *
from tmp
where col1 = '1aagacdaafasd' and col2 in ('X', 'Y', 'Z');
```

The best index is a composite index: `tmp(col1, col2)`.  The order of the keys in the index is important, `col1` needs to be before `col2`.

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff

Comment: What do you think about bitmap index, would not it be more efficient in this case?